# Cannot find the desired link for download (Python BeautifulSoup)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I am pretty new to Python Beautiful Soup and I don't have much knowledge about html or js. I tried to use bs4 to download all xls files in this [page](http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/app/iowa/2017/downloads), but it seems that bs4 cannot find the links under "attachment" section. Could someone help me out?

**My current code is:**

```
"""
Scrapping of all county-level raw data from 
http://www.countyhealthrankings.org for all years. Data stored in RawData 
folder.
Code modified from https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/download-all-
pdfs-webpage-with-python-script-0163031/
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urlparse
import urllib2
import os
import sys

"""
Get all links
"""
def getAllLinks(url):
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    return links

def download(links):
    for link in links:
        #raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
        #print link
        #print "------------------------------------"
        #print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(link['href']))
        #print "------------------------------------"
        #print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(link['href']))[1]
        suffix = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(link['href']))[1]
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(link['href']))[1] == '.xls':
            print link #cannot find anything
            currentLink = urllib2.urlopen(link)

links = 
getAllLinks("http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/app/iowa/2017/downloads")
download(links)
```

(By the way, my desired link looks like [this](http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2010%20County%20Health%20Ranking%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v2.xls).)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be one of the tasks for which BeautifulSoup (in itself, at least) is inadequate. You can, however, do it with selenium.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/app/iowa/2017/downloads')
>>> links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="file"]/a')
>>> len(links)
30
>>> for link in links:
...     link.get_attribute('href')
...     
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/CHR2017_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2017%20County%20Health%20Rankings%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v1.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2017%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2017%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/CHR2016_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2016%20County%20Health%20Rankings%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v3.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2016%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2016%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/CHR2015_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2015%20County%20Health%20Rankings%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v3.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2015%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2015%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/CHR2014_IA_v2.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2014%20County%20Health%20Rankings%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v6.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2014%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2014%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/states/CHR2013_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2013%20County%20Health%20Ranking%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v1_0.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2013%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2013%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/states/CHR2012_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2012%20County%20Health%20Ranking%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v2.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2012%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2012%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/states/CHR2011_IA.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2011%20County%20Health%20Ranking%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v2.xls'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2011%20Health%20Outcomes%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2011%20Health%20Factors%20-%20Iowa.png'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/states/CHR2010_IA_0.pdf'
'http://www.countyhealthrankings.org/sites/default/files/state/downloads/2010%20County%20Health%20Ranking%20Iowa%20Data%20-%20v2.xls'
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. This seems to work! Just curious, do you happen to know why BeautifulSoup doesn't work well in this case?

Comment: This should have been in my answer. I was suspicious because your code looked ok. I tried using BeautifulSoup to find all of the links on the page and printing out their hrefs. None of these were what we wanted which suggested to me that the page is likely using Ajax to load its own contents. This is practically the norm these days. You can still use BeautifulSoup but often you will have to load a page's DOM with the facilities of a product like selenium. BeautifulSoup can't process what isn't loaded in HTML.

Comment: Uh OK. Thanks:))